# Why does powershell executes my property getters

Tags: powershell

I have a C# project that I'm consuming with PowerShell.
A method returns an object that have not been fully initialized and that calls P/Invoke under the hood through `get` properties.

When I call the method, the script crashes because of an accessViolationException that is caused by the call of a property on that partially initialized object, but I didn't call it.
Why do Powershell act like this? is there an option to disable that "eager property evaluation"?

The original issue is the one posted here: https://github.com/ZeBobo5/Vlc.DotNet/issues/330

```
Add-Type -Path ".\Other\VLC\Vlc.DotNet.Core.dll"
Add-Type -Path ".\Other\VLC\Vlc.DotNet.Core.Interops.dll"

$Cameras = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
$Test = New-Object System.Uri("rtsp://192.168.0.50/axis-media/media.amp?camera=1")
$Cameras.Add($Test)

$VlcLibDirPath = (Get-Location).Path + ".\Other\VLC\libvlc_x64"
$VlcLibDir = New-Object System.IO.DirectoryInfo($VlcLibDirPath)
$VlcOpt = "--rtsp-user=admin", "--rtsp-pwd=12345"
$Plyr = New-Object Vlc.DotNet.Core.VlcMediaPlayer($VlcLibDir, $VlcOpt)
for ($i=0; $i -lt $Cameras.Count; $i++)
{
    $Plyr.SetMedia($Cameras[$i]) #Fails here with System.AccessViolationException
    $Plyr.Play
    $Plyr.Stop
}
```

`SetMedia` returns a `VlcMedia`, which contains a `Statistics` property, which is automatically invoked by PowerShell.

Code for `VlcMedia` can be found here : https://github.com/ZeBobo5/Vlc.DotNet/blob/develop/src/Vlc.DotNet.Core/VlcMedia/VlcMedia.cs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's difficult to tell without seeing your code, but there's tons of ways this could be happening. If the object is being displayed at all, the properties are probably all being read.

You should change those to methods, and then they won't get read without specifically being invoked.

Or, change your getters to detect an uninitialized object (you should be doing this already if it's possible for consumers to end up with such an object).

### Edit:

With your code posted, it's clear:

```
$Plyr.SetMedia($Cameras[$i]) #Fails here with System.AccessViolationException
```

> `SetMedia` returns a `VlcMedia`, which contains a `Statistics` property, which is automatically invoked by PowerShell.

Everything returned in PowerShell goes somewhere. If you don't assign it or redirect it, it gets sent to the pipeline.

It seems that you don't want or need the output from this method, so you should either assign it to a variable or dispose of the return in one of a few ways:

```
[null]$Plyr.SetMedia($Cameras[$i]) 
$null = $Plyr.SetMedia($Cameras[$i]) 
$Plyr.SetMedia($Cameras[$i]) | Out-Null
```

(note: piping to `Out-Null` is the least performant, which is magnified since you're doing this in a loop)

If you want to use the value later (not shown in your code), assign it and use it later.